# Different style for first two (sticky) posts

Tags: loop, homepage, sticky-post

I'm currently facing a few loose ends while dealing with the homepage of a theme I am working on. I got my loop set up to show the most recent posts in a certain style and it works perfectly.

Now I am trying to position two sticky posts (or even posts from a certain category) on top of that loop, utilizing different styling and showing only a thumbnail and the headline. I want them to be up there no matter how old they are and want the regular loop to begin just below of them. Like on a typical magazine website, the top content stays where it is while the blog content below gets new posts more often. Please see attached draft.

[image: Sticky posts above loop]

I really don't know how to incorporate the two posts above my loop. I'd really appreciate any hint in the right direction where to start.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add a css class and in your loop, put a `$i` and let `$i` run, `if $i == 2` then you add the css class attribute to that sticky post.

```
$i = 0;
while( have_posts() ):
         the_post();
   $i++;
   if($i == 2):
      $css_class = 'top-sticky';
   else:
      $css_class = ''; 
   endif;

endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Sounds like a quite simple solution. But wouldn't I need to define two classes for if `$i == 1` and `$i == 2` (like top-sticky-one and top-sticky-two) two put both posts in different columns (in Bootstrap for example)?

Answer (score 0):

You first need to have some way of marking these posts as they might change in time. Your best bet is to use a "special" tag (like `featured`) like Jetpack's [Featured Content](https://jetpack.com/support/featured-content/) module does (it also gives you a nice way of deciding what tag to use via the Customizer).

After you have that setup, you use a custom query loop and display only those posts above the regular loop.

To keep those featured posts out of the regular/main loop, you need to use the `pre_get_posts` action hook and, depending on certain conditions (maybe you only show the featured posts on your homepage - `is_home()`, not in category or tags archives), you exclude those posts by setting the `post__not_in` [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters) parameter.